# 1 particular category crashes our magento website

Tags: category

There is a category on our magento website which crashes the site.

Website: http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/

The category: http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/accessories

I cannot understand why. I have tried renaming the category, no joy.
I have changed it from displaying a CMS block to just displaying products, no joy.

I have tried multiple browsers, it's not a browser issue.

Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: Welcome to MSE, when I check the response of `http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/accessories` page, it already made `301` redirection on `http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/our-accessories` page. So please debug `our-accessories` instead `accessories`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned. It was originally accessories but I change to our-accessories in the magento backend to see if this would fix the problem but it didn't unfortunately.

Comment: You need to do little debugging to rectify the issue and your staring point be `viewAction()` of `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController` class. Put PHP `die()` or `exit()` to force fully terminate execution in this method.

Comment: To complete Jayesh answer, take care if this your production environment with the `die;` and `exit` this will affect all your categories for all visitors. Don't forget to use IP testing around your debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLVED***

I had an issue with reindexing being stuck. My hosting provider said "Php memory limit set on the server was causing the problem. I have increased the memory limit set on the server to 1GB and now your reindexing is working fine"

This in turn also fixed my issue of the magento category crashing the website.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your URL http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/accessories is redirecting to http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/our-accessories.

It may be an infinite loop if :
 - http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/accessories redirects to http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/our-accessories
 - http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/our-accessories redirects-to http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/accessories
 - http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/accessories redirects to http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/our-accessories
 - etc

---

You  can take a look at this suggestion, you can also look into your server log if there is another error in your `access.log` / `error.log` files

---

**EDIT** It seems that you redirect URL is not reachable. Take a look at the server log files.

```
$ curl -I http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/accessories
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2016 10:30:55 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.44
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: /our-accessories
Content-Type: text/html
```

```
$ curl -I --max-time 1 http://www.radiatorline.co.uk/our-accessories
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 1004 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

Comment: If there is an infinite redirect loop, doesn't the browser normally let you know?

Comment: Yes I agree but we have not much informations here so this is a lead I give you ;) Did you check the server logs ?

Comment: Appreciate your help. system.log was 500MB so I deleted it now another version has been created with file permission 640 and I cannot view/edit/delete or change permission on it.. I have submitted a ticket with hosting company to help me out. Once that small issue is resolved I will visit the broken webpage and then check log :)

Comment: I add an edit with some test that proof your redirect URL `our-accessories` is your problem.

Comment: Did you test this in another environment that your production ? Maybe there is a conflict with a CMS with the same `url_key` or something like this. In a test environment enable all the debug tools `developer mode` and check again.

Comment: We currently do not have a demo/test enviroment set up. We are working on this. Below is what I can find in system.log - it's the same 3 lines repeated lots and lots of times

Comment: 2016-03-14T12:00:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /home/radiatorli/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

2016-03-14T12:00:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt; ?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot;?&gt;  in /home/radiatorli/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

2016-03-14T12:00:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():   ^  in /home/radiatorli/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

Comment: That mean you have a non XML character at the end of one of your XML file. In my opinion this is not your current problem because you do not have it everywhere. Try to enable the developer mode for your IP only